# NVidia PerfHUD ES Tegra on Google Nexus 7

Tags: android, opengl-es, profiling, tegra

I'm trying to use [NVIDIA PerfHUD ES](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-perfhud-es) on Google Nexus 7 over ADB.
I have enabled debugging using batch file, but I can't connect to device.
Looking at LogCat I can see that device can't start communication.
NVPerfHUD ES is active
k:Error creating socket
Communication layer init failed

And when I start PerfHUD on PC It can't connect.

Documentation mentions something about setting firewall correctly but I'm not sure which firewall on PC or on device (is there firewall on device?)

I'm curently out of ideas, rebooted device few times etc but still no luck.
Any ideas what can I do?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you list out what you batch file does to enabled debugging. Also does the app have INTERNET permission (per the documentation.)

Comment: THANK YOU! That's it! I was missing internet permission in my project, it is new project and I haven't needed any connectivity and I didn't add permission to manifest file.

Comment: I'm using batch "enable_perfhud.bat" from tegra toolkit, and there is only two lines in it.
---
pushd "%~dp0"
adb shell setprop debug.perfhudes 1
---
If anyone from nvidia reads this... I would be realy good to update documentation with this internet permission because it is easy to overlook it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation requires the app have INTERNET permission. Also the batch script from the toolkit doesn't handle the case if you have happen to have a device and emulator running, so it should only be run when there is only one entry when you run the 'adb devices' command.